# iOS: Bad access is cxx_descruct

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I have a problem with an app crashing for a few users, I have no idea whats causing it and all I got is this stacktrace from crashlytics:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194e5016c objc_release + 12
1  learnchinese                   0x00000001000a95a0 -[WGRLanguageLabel .cxx_destruct] (WGRLanguageLabel.m:34)
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194e36b1c object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194e43f38 objc_destructInstance + 92
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194e43f90 object_dispose + 28
5  UIKit                          0x0000000187f8771c -[UIResponder dealloc] + 116
6  UIKit                          0x0000000187c3dc38 -[UIView dealloc] + 1000
7  learnchinese                   0x00000001000a5460 -[WGRLanguageLabel dealloc] (WGRLanguageLabel.m:39)
8  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830a10f8 CFRelease + 524
9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830ad6b8 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 152
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194e51724 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 564
11 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830a4d14 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
12 UIKit                          0x0000000187c34584 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 76
13 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018317bff0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183178f7c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
15 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018317935c __CFRunLoopRun + 836
16 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830a4f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
17 GraphicsServices               0x000000018cb076fc GSEventRunModal + 168
18 UIKit                          0x0000000187ca6d94 UIApplicationMain + 1488
19 learnchinese                   0x00000001001679ec main (main.m:13)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001954e2a08 start + 4
```

It looks like WGRLanguageLabel has been released when auto release pool try to release it again.

Here is the dealloc method in WGRLanguageLabel:

```
@implementation WGRLanguageLabel

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

...
@end
```

Comment: Try using instruments and looking at zombies. (There is a tutorial here:http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks)

Comment: Post your related code about the `WGRLanguageLabel`

Comment: I have put the code of -dealloc method. Any more code required?

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC.